# exporting C++ object into R using Rcpp and exposing some of the class methods from external C++ library

Tags: r, rcpp, sbml

I am trying to return an object in an Rcpp based package in which is of type `libsbml::Model` from the `libsbml` [C++ library](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/class_model.html)

In the end, I want my package to be able to do something like this in `R`

```
m <- getModel("text.xml")
m$getListofParameters
```

I am trying the following to return the model

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP getModel (std::string fname) {

  libsbml::SBMLReader reader;
  libsbml::SBMLDocument* document = reader.readSBMLFromFile(fname);

  libsbml::Model* model = document->getModel();

  // Rcpp::XPtr<libsbml::Model> modelPtr(model);
  // return Rcpp::wrap(modePtr);

  return Rcpp::wrap(*model);

}
```

It is giving me an obvious error, 
`cannot initialize a variable of type "SEXP' (aka 'SEXPREC *') with an lvalue of type 'libsbml::Model *const'`

probably because I need to expand `wrap` to return `libsbml::Model` type (I think), based on a recent [article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/) in `Rcpp` gallery. Am I on the right track with this thinking? It seems like a huge task because `libsbml::Model` is a huge class and I am a novice in C++ with no experience in object-oriented programming.

I also attempted the following code (using `Rcpp` modules)

```
RCPP_MODULE(sbModel){

  using namespace Rcpp ;

  // we expose the class libsbml::Model as "Model" on the R side
  class_<libsbml::Model>("Model")

    // exposing the default constructor
    .constructor<unsigned int, unsigned int>("Creates a new Model using the given SBML level and version values.")

    // exposing member functions -- taken directly from libsbml::Model
    .method( "getListofParameters", &libsbml::Model::getListOfParameters(),"Get the list of Parameters of the model")

}
```

in order to expose some of the methods of `libsbml::Model` class. But I am getting the following message on `Clean and Rebuild` command on package

`call to non-static member function without an object argument`

Sorry for the vague question, but any pointers on how to achieve my final goal of exporting `libsbml::Model` into `R` and exposing some of fields of that class would be really appreciated. The final version of code can be found at -

https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbml/blob/master/src/getModel.cpp

Comment: `&libsbml::Model::getListOfParameters()` should not have parentheses.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell - I removed the parenthesis, now I am getting - `call to member function 'method' is ambigious` error though.

Comment: Simplify simplify simplify. Start with a simpler Rcpp Modules use case, maybe a local baby class.  Then add the SBML headers, then instantiate one SBML object and so on.

Comment: Does the error message say `'method'` literally, or the actual method name?   I don't have a copy of that library, and I'm not about to download one just to debug your code, so I would also recommend that you begin with a minimal test case. Rcpp modules [do work](https://github.com/nathan-russell/hashmap/blob/master/src/hashmap.cpp), whether or not the code is coming from a 3rd party library should have no bearing on this.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is covered in the modules vignette: *"Const and non-const member functions method is able to expose both const and non const member functions
of a class. There are however situations where a class defines two versions of the same method, differing only in their
signature by the const-ness. It is for example the case of the member functions back of the std::vector template from
the STL. [...] **To resolve the ambiguity, it is possible to use const_method or nonconst_method instead of method in order to restrict
the candidate methods**."*.

Comment: Additionally, `getListOfParameters` [seems to return a pointer](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/class_model.html#ab642033b80481b4db9a1c350adc567cc), so you will need to write a `Rcpp::wrap` specialization for `ListOfParameters*` or use some other means of abstraction.

Comment: @nrussell, @dirk, thank you for your helpful suggestions. It seems there are many many steps in between (e.g., simple SBML class, `Rcpp::wrap`) etc. before I get to the final form I want.

Comment: @SN248: Separate the two aspects.  First, build a minimal module instantiating _something_ from SBML.  No fancy interfacing -- maybe an `int` in and a modified `int` out.  Make sure that builds, loads, ...   Only then worry about `wrap()` and `as<>()` which is totally different topic unrelated to Modules (and more difficult).